# Default text appearing in the password text box ..how to make it disappear?

Tags: asp.net

Even though "Text" property is set to Text=""

```
asp:TextBox MaxLength="256"  runat="server" ID="passwordTxt" TextMode="Password" Text=""
```

I also tried this on Page_load :-

```
passwordTxt.Text="";
```

I am still seeing 5 dots in the Password text box..How to make it go away ? Why is it there anyway ? like why ?

[EDIT]

I was not able to see Bold, Code tag buttons when posting this ques..so couldnt include my code lines inside of code tags..whats wrong with this website ??

[EDIT2]
ok I can see the buttons now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the browser auto-populating for you. View the source, it will be empty.

Comment: yeah I figured..but now that I have cleared cache, form history and reloaded the page..it still is displaying that default text..Why now ? So is it the browser only ??coz the text box got no text...its empty only..its Firefox btw

Comment: It is the browser. Try it in a different browser. The passwords are stored in a seperate area, not in the cache or form history. They are under "Saved Passwords" in Firefox.

Comment: oh ok..didnt know that..thnx..its not displaying default text in IE..was firefox only

Answer (score 0):

To stop firefox auto prompting to save this data in a form, add the following property to the form tag

autocomplete="off"

i.e. :
    form id="myForm" runat="server" autocomplete="off"